# Django like filter for SQL query filter

Tags: sql, django, django-orm, django-filter

How can i implement same django type filtering using SQL query. In django if i need to filter based on multiple column value i can again filter the query sets using .filter.

For Example in Django:
Model is Employee

```
data = Employee.objects.all()
if employee_department!='':
  data = data.filter(empdept=employee_department)
if employee_location!=''
  data = data.filter(emploc=employee_location)
```

*How can  i achieve this in SQL like filtering the query results*

Comment: Do you want to use `.filter().filter()` in SQL or to use if condition in SQL?

Comment: Can you please more elaborate the question by sharing the `Employee` model also?

Comment: You can see the SQL queryset produces using `query` property. In your case call`str(data.query)` and see the result